# Angular Unit Tests are Annoying: Don't find Issues at Build/Compile Time

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular10

Everytime, I am writing tests for Angular, my tests fail at run execution time, rather than build time. No Provider found for this, no provider found, etc NULL,   how can I find all these issues at Build Compile time? rather than filling in missing providers at runtime? All I do is keep going back and forth between Google. This is why React has top market share now.

I googled to fix this, now have 10 more, is there a quick efficient solution to resolve all this?

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're building your tests you have to provide all the services etc that are passed into your constructor. Since the test is actually trying to bootstrap and build your component/service/directive it requires these providers to work.

In your `beforeEach(() => {})` you actually need to pass in an providers/imports that are needed along with their default methods/variables. A good library to help with this is [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) which actually stubs out a mock service/provider for you.

Here's an example:

```
beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
        providers: [MockProvider(MyTestService)],
    }),
);
```